# Swift - push alert action to show new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

How to show or link to new ViewController when push button on alert?

[image]

This is my code

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: validateQRObj.responseDescription, message: validateQRObj.productName, preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductDetialViewController")
    self.present(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
alert.addAction(action)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What issue are you having with the code you posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Control drag from View Controller 1 (The yellow dot) to any where on View Controller 2 and then click on the Segue. Show the Attributes inspector and  Under Storyboard Segue identifier name the identifier VC2

If this is the answer you were looking for don't forget to except the answer.

```
func alert(){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Open View Controller. ", message: "Press  Ok  to open View Controller number 2.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
    //The (withIdentifier: "VC2") is the Storyboard Segue identifier.
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "VC2", sender: self)
 })

    alertController.addAction(ok)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it doesn't work. I made :

```
    func alert(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let twop = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Accueil") as! Accueil
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Open new View !", message: "Clic to ok", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        self.navigationController?.show(twop, sender: self)
    })

    alertController.addAction(ok)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and now it's working !!